# Angular giving error "Model is not of type `number`" when typeof === number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As a work around to not being able to filter inputs without directives I've attempted the following:

On the input [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) detects a change and runs a function. The input has `type="number"`

```
<input type="number"
       ng-model="ctrl.met.mass"
       ng-change="ctrl.met.update.mass()">
```

The function updates some other fields, then formats them. In this example I want it to display two decimal points with [toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). This is done with variable = variable.toFixed(2)

```
ctrl.met.cost = ctrl.met.mass * ctrl.met.price;
ctrl.imp.mass = ctrl.met.mass * 0.0353;
ctrl.imp.cost = ctrl.imp.mass * ctrl.imp.price;

console.log(typeof ctrl.met.mass); // number

ctrl.met.mass = ctrl.met.mass.toFixed(2);
console.log(typeof ctrl.met.mass); //string
```

But the number isn't formatting as well as I'm receiving [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt?p0=29.00); note the number at the end of the URL is 29.00, being the desired result. If the number is 12.34 that would be in place of 29.00.

```
Error: ngModel:numfmt
Model is not of type `number`
```

But when I run typeof ctrl.met.mass at any point, or any other variable I'm working with, it's telling me it is in fact a number except after .toFixed() has interacted with it.

The same error has occurred with the [Angular Number Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) (after injecting), [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and [toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) (to a precision of 4, to ensure two decimal places for a two digit number).

```
ctrl.met.mass = $filter("number")(ctrl.met.mass, 2);
ctrl.met.mass = $filter("number")(parseInt/Float/Precision(ctrl.met.mass), 2);
ctrl.met.mass = ctrl.met.mass.toInt/Float
ctrl.met.mass = ctrl.met.mass.Precision(4);
```

I'm thinking I won't be able to do so this way, and will need to use a directive. Before I try that though, why is this happening and can it be worked around?

edit: It seems what I'm trying is impossible. Upon setting ctrl.met.mass to what was, without a doubt, a number with two decimal places it rejected it in preference for an integer. If anyone knows why this is the case, please share.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value from the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method is a string. So you need to convert it to float in your controller:

```
var fixed = ctrl.met.mass.toFixed(2);
ctrl.met.mass = parseFloat(fixed);
```

Comment: Douh' reading more documentation I think this could be incorrect. Could you test it?

Comment: While I'm not getting any errors the number is becoming fixed to not having a decimal point. For example if I have 29 in the input and type ".5" it changes to 29 right away. Pasting a number in with any number of decimal places does the same. The same result occurred using this idea but the methods I linked to in the question. While using this I was no longer getting typeof === string anywhere.

Comment: You will have a new issue there. The input of type number is accepting integers only. You'll need to use a normal input in order to display them correctly, check [this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/filter/number) example.

Comment: It seems angular will only allow ctrl.met.mass to be an integer. I think I've hit something which is impossible without adjusting constraints.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a stringToNumber directive to parse string to number, the perfect example of this is shown at below link :
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt